# .htaccess redirecting old to new url RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've a issue with my .htaccess to redirect old url to new url.

I've a old url with the follow: example.com/?q=content/my-content

I'm using the follow rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q\=(.+)
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

My worst problem is when users access my site by google results, because the redirect put the follow url: example.com/content/content/my-content.

Please help me.